# virtualenv using wrong django

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv all set up with the `--no-site-packages` flag on.

When I did `pip install django==1.3` everything seemed to install just fine.

When I ran `python manage.py sycndb` I get the error.

`ImportError django.contrib.staticfiles: No module named staticfiles`

I know this is a feature of 1.3 and should work. When I go in to the python shell and type

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 2, 1, 'alpha', 0)
```

Any idea why I get back 1.2 I have the vitrualenv on and know I am in it because I can import other things I have installed. Everything but django seems to work. It seems I am getting a ghost verson or another version installed on my machine, but that shouldnt happen beacause of the --no-site-packages, right?

Comment: Just made an empty brand new `virtualenv --no-site-packages venv` went in `source bin/active` , then python. Still getting back django.VERSION 1.2.

Comment: Don't know what system you're on, but maybe your paths are somehow mixed up and some wrong python interpreter is run. Try explicitly running `bin/python` in your virtualenv!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you perform the following checks:

1. Are you using python from your virtualenv?

   `which python`

   `/home/raisins/.virtualenvs/yourenv/bin/python`
2. Open a python shell and check where your django is coming from:

   `python`

   `>>> import django`

   `>>> django.__path__`

   `>>> ['/home/raisins/.virtualenvs/yourenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django']`
3. When you run your `pip install` command, have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: Solved it. It seems awhile ago. I hard coded django path to in my `.bash_profile` and That seemed to be overriding my django calls.

Comment: @Raisins This is exactly the problem I was having, and I couldn't figure out why! Thanks for pointing this out.