# How do I force a new version of Django in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I want to install **version 1.3.1** of Django in a new virtualenv. I already have Django version 1.3.0 installed system-wide. I have installed the virtualenv with `no-site-packages` and attempted to reinstall Django as follows, but with no success:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages pyenv
New python executable in pyenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
$ source pyenv/bin/activate
(pyenv)$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 26 2011, 21:27:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 0, 'final', 0)
```

OK, so even though I haven't installed Django and I have used `no-site-packages`, the virtualenv has still somehow picked up the system version.

Now to try to over-write it with version 1.3.1:

```
(pyenv)$ pip install django==1.3.1
Downloading/unpacking django==1.3.1
  Downloading Django-1.3.1.tar.gz (6.5Mb): 6.5Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django
Installing collected packages: django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.3
    Not uninstalling Django at /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages, outside environment /Users/anna/Dropbox/code-local/pyenv/pyenv/bin/..
  Running setup.py install for django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/django-admin.py from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /Users/anna/Dropbox/code-local/pyenv/pyenv/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(pyenv)$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 26 2011, 21:27:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
```

That hasn't worked, it's still pointing at 1.3.0!

Note the line: `Found existing installation: Django 1.3 Not uninstalling Django`.

How can I force my virtualenv to use 1.3.1? Do I need to edit my local Python path?

I'm confused as to why the virtualenv can even see the system Django when I've explicitly installed with `no-site-packages`. Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Try telling pip to ignore installed packages with `-I`. You probably also want to specify the directory for your virtualenv with with `-E /path/to/env`

Comment: try this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569895/virtualenv-using-wrong-django

Answer (score 4):

After you've created and activated the virtualenv with `--no-site-packages`, there should be no access to django package.
I assume you somehow modified the `PYTHONPATH` to provide it. `echo $PYTHONPATH` (mine is empty string)
Try running `pip freeze`, this is how it looks for me:

```
 $> virtualenv --no-site-packages testenv 
 New python executable in testenv/bin/python2.7
 Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
 Installing setuptools............done.
 Installing pip...............done.
 $> source testenv/bin/activate
 (testenv)$> pip freeze
 wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use -U option to upgrade.

> pip install -U django==1.3.1

Comment: Nope, just run that, still getting `Found existing installation: Django 1.3    Not uninstalling Django` and `>>> django.VERSION
(1, 3, 0, 'final', 0)`.

Comment: `pip install -U django` should be enough, since it will pull the latest automatically. Not sure why that wouldn't have worked as is, though. You can also try `pip install -I django`, which will ignore installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of forcing django 1.3.1, you should take one step back and investigate at the causes that might have gone wrong:

- What's the contents of the `site-packages` directory in the virtual environment?
- What's the value of `django.__file__` for the version being imported
- Is there any customization maybe in `site.py` or are you using a user site directory?

For what is worth, I used the same command with the `--no-site-packages` option and I wasn't able to import the django version installed system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with my virtualenv. I solved my problem with this steps:

Open shell and type:

```
python

import django

django.__path__
```

this will tell you the path you should remove old version of django.

Go to that directory and use root options (i think u need this for removing the directory) with sudo and type these commands:

```
rm -r Django
rm -r Django-1.3.0.egg-info/
```

At last, install Django 1.3.1